# Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Im currently using vs2008 with asp.net mvc framework for web development. 
Im missing a feature/configuration: When I change to another .cs file I want the "class view" to automatically show me what methods the active .cs file contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can set it up that way, but I use the [Source Code Outliner Power Toy](http://www.codeplex.com/SourceCodeOutliner). It leaves the Class View to be freely explored and adds a window with a filterable, searchable list showing you what the active .cs file contains (not only methods, but everything).

Answer (score 1):

This is also available in the [File Structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#File_Structure) window from ReSharper.